# Filter an IEnumerable from another list

Tags: c#, list, generics, filter, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<int>` with items `1, 5, 10, 85, 96`, and another 
`IEnumerable<Hw> lstHw`, where the `Hw` class has property `HwID`.

I want to filter the `IEnumerable<int>` to get the values that are not present in the `IEnumerable<Hw>` (`HwID`).

So the output should give me: `1, 5, 85`

How we can do that?

Comment: Providing the code you have already used would be far more helpful. This site is to help with code ... not code writing service

Comment: Please sohw code that initializes two lists with the values you're speaking of, and show the expected results.

Comment: IEnumerable<Int32> hwids = scopedZcat.GetProductsByFamily(auto.PlatformID);
                            IEnumerable<uint> selectedHwId = lstZcatCases.Where(c => c.CaseID == auto.CaseID).Select(i => i.HWID).ToList(); , now i want hwids which are not there in selectedHwid

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this corectly, you want to get all the integers from the `List<int>` that don't have a corresponding `Hw` in the other list with an `HWId` that matches.

If so, you can use the `System.Linq` methods `Where` to filter out items where `All` the items in `lstHw` do not have an `HwID` that matches:

```
var ints = new List<int> {1, 5, 10, 85, 96};
var lstHw = new List<Hw> {new Hw {HwID = 10}, new Hw {HwID = 96}};

var results = ints.Where(i => lstHw.All(hw => hw.HwID != i));
```

---

Update
Based on your code in the comments section, it seems like you actually have two `List<int>` collections (well, one is a `List<uint>`). Here's your comment:

```
IEnumerable<Int32> hwids = scopedZcat.GetProductsByFamily(auto.PlatformID);
IEnumerable<uint> selectedHwId = lstZcatCases
    .Where(c => c.CaseID != auto.CaseID)
    .Select(i => i.HWID)
    .ToList(); 

// Now I want the hwids which are not there in selectedHwid
```

If that's the case, then this should do the trick:

```
// Note that we have to cast a `uint` to an `int`
var results = hwids.Except(selectedHwId.Select(id => (int)id));
```